# Active Record 'Is not null' query very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

### Expected behavior:

Expect return data is not null more fast

### Actual behavior:

**I'm try run this query but is very slow spend so much time:**

```
result.distinct(true)
.where(obras: { id: construction_site_id })
.where.not(dados_inspecao: { quantidade_erros: 0} )
.where.not(dados_inspecao: { quantidade_erros: nil } )
```

If I run without 'is not null' statement is pretty fast

I try this query on pgAdmin 3 and is very fast (with is not null):

```
SELECT DISTINCT servicos.id, servicos.titulo as service_title, sum(quantidade_erros) as qtd FROM "dados_inspecao" INNER JOIN "fvs_metodos_verificados" ON "fvs_metodos_verificados"."id" = "dados_inspecao"."fvs_metodos_verificados_id" INNER JOIN "fvs_preenchimento" ON "fvs_preenchimento"."id" = "fvs_metodos_verificados"."fvs_preenchimento_id" INNER JOIN "fvs" ON "fvs"."id" = "fvs_preenchimento"."fvs_id" AND "fvs"."empresas_id" = 44093 INNER JOIN "atividade" ON "atividade"."id" = "fvs_preenchimento"."atividade_id" AND "atividade"."empresas_id" = 44093 INNER JOIN "servicos" ON "servicos"."id" = "atividade"."servicos_id" AND "servicos"."empresas_id" = 44093 INNER JOIN "local" ON "local"."id" = "atividade"."local_id" INNER JOIN "obras" ON "obras"."id" = "local"."obras_id" AND "obras"."empresas_id" = 44093 WHERE "obras"."id" = 96520 AND ("dados_inspecao"."quantidade_erros" != 0) AND ("dados_inspecao"."quantidade_erros" IS NULL) GROUP BY servicos.id
```

I already try this and I had no success:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(%Q{ SELECT DISTINCT servicos.id, servicos.titulo as service_title, sum(quantidade_erros) as qtd FROM "dados_inspecao" INNER JOIN "fvs_metodos_verificados" ON "fvs_metodos_verificados"."id" = "dados_inspecao"."fvs_metodos_verificados_id" INNER JOIN "fvs_preenchimento" ON "fvs_preenchimento"."id" = "fvs_metodos_verificados"."fvs_preenchimento_id" INNER JOIN "fvs" ON "fvs"."id" = "fvs_preenchimento"."fvs_id" AND "fvs"."empresas_id" = 44093 INNER JOIN "atividade" ON "atividade"."id" = "fvs_preenchimento"."atividade_id" AND "atividade"."empresas_id" = 44093 INNER JOIN "servicos" ON "servicos"."id" = "atividade"."servicos_id" AND "servicos"."empresas_id" = 44093 INNER JOIN "local" ON "local"."id" = "atividade"."local_id" INNER JOIN "obras" ON "obras"."id" = "local"."obras_id" AND "obras"."empresas_id" = 44093 WHERE "obras"."id" = 96520 AND ("dados_inspecao"."quantidade_erros" != 0) AND ("dados_inspecao"."quantidade_erros" IS NULL) GROUP BY servicos.id })
```

### System configuration:

Rails version: 4.2.0

Ruby version: 2.2.5

Postgres: 9.5

**[Edit]**

### Explain Analyze output on postgres:

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=7881.74..7881.75 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=66.832..66.832 rows=4 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: servicos.id, servicos.titulo, sum(dados_inspecao.quantidade_erros)"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=7881.73..7881.74 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=66.825..66.825 rows=4 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: servicos.id"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4240.53..7881.72 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=26.741..66.766 rows=55 loops=1)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4240.38..7873.55 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=26.709..66.545 rows=55 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4240.10..7872.44 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=26.694..66.311 rows=55 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4239.82..7871.98 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=26.687..66.087 rows=55 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=4239.40..7811.45 rows=47 width=8) (actual time=26.669..65.739 rows=55 loops=1)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (fvs_metodos_verificados.id = dados_inspecao.fvs_metodos_verificados_id)"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=793.60..4342.23 rows=1836 width=8) (actual time=8.161..47.684 rows=10202 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (fvs_metodos_verificados.fvs_preenchimento_id = fvs_preenchimento.id)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on fvs_metodos_verificados  (cost=0.00..2980.10 rows=146710 width=8) (actual time=0.004..18.224 rows=146710 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=791.63..791.63 rows=158 width=8) (actual time=5.505..5.505 rows=623 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 33kB"
"                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=74.41..791.63 rows=158 width=8) (actual time=0.514..5.375 rows=623 loops=1)"
"                                                        Hash Cond: (fvs_preenchimento.fvs_id = fvs.id)"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on fvs_preenchimento  (cost=0.00..668.28 rows=12628 width=12) (actual time=0.003..3.468 rows=12628 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=73.95..73.95 rows=37 width=4) (actual time=0.477..0.477 rows=37 loops=1)"
"                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on fvs  (cost=0.00..73.95 rows=37 width=4) (actual time=0.038..0.467 rows=37 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Filter: (empresas_id = 44093)"
"                                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2919"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=3398.39..3398.39 rows=3793 width=8) (actual time=15.435..15.435 rows=3901 loops=1)"
"                                            Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 185kB"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on dados_inspecao  (cost=0.00..3398.39 rows=3793 width=8) (actual time=0.005..14.312 rows=3901 loops=1)"
"                                                  Filter: ((quantidade_erros IS NOT NULL) AND (quantidade_erros <> 0))"
"                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 121170"
"                                ->  Index Scan using atividade_pkey on atividade  (cost=0.41..1.28 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=55)"
"                                      Index Cond: (id = fvs_preenchimento.atividade_id)"
"                                      Filter: (empresas_id = 44093)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using servicos_pkey on servicos  (cost=0.28..0.46 rows=1 width=43) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=55)"
"                                Index Cond: (id = atividade.servicos_id)"
"                                Filter: (empresas_id = 44093)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using local_pkey on local  (cost=0.29..1.09 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=55)"
"                          Index Cond: (id = atividade.local_id)"
"                          Filter: (obras_id = 96520)"
"              ->  Index Scan using obras_pkey on obras  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=55)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = 96520)"
"                    Filter: (empresas_id = 44093)"
"Planning time: 3.469 ms"
"Execution time: 66.995 ms"
```

Comment: Can you post your models?  At least post the associations in your models.

Comment: You need to measure it. First, call `#to_sql` on the Active Record relation to get the SQL generated (or find it in `log/development.log`). Then connect to Postgres and run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and post the results here.

Comment: Look the question again I did edit and add the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output

Comment: Can you add the SQL (i.e. `to_sql`) as well?

Comment: It is already on question

Comment: Ah...so the question contains the SQL generated by Rails?  I thought that was a query you wrote.   My mistake.  Anyway, it looks like you could use some indexes.  I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks for you help me and I already solve the problem the explain is on above comments answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem with this slow query today, the problem was scoped query this verifies many times for **"empresas_id" = 44093**, I removed this and works very well. Thanks

- `INNER JOIN "fvs" ON "fvs"."id" = "fvs_preenchimento"."fvs_id" AND "fvs"."empresas_id" = 44093`
- `INNER JOIN "atividade" ON "atividade"."id" = "fvs_preenchimento"."atividade_id" AND "atividade"."empresas_id" = 44093`
- `INNER JOIN "servicos" ON "servicos"."id" = "atividade"."servicos_id" AND "servicos"."empresas_id" = 44093`
- `INNER JOIN "obras" ON "obras"."id" = "local"."obras_id" AND "obras"."empresas_id" = 44093`

Answer (score 1):

This may be faster:

```
result.distinct(true)
  .where(obras: { id: construction_site_id })
  .where.not(dados_inspecao: { quantidade_erros: [0,nil]} )
```

You also may want to make sure you have an index on all of your `id`s and foreign keys. You may also want to add an index to `quantidade_erros`.

I would add indexes to the following:

- `fvs_metodos_verificados.fvs_preenchimento_id`
- `fvs_preenchimento.fvs_id`
- `fvs.empreses.id`
- `dados_inspecao.quantidade_errors`

You should be able to do this with a migration. Run:

`rails g migration AddIndeciesToForeignKeys`

Then modify the generated migration file:

```
class AddIndeciesToForeignKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  add_index: :fvs_metodos_verificados, :fvs_preenchimento_id
  add_index: :fvs_preenchimento, :fvs_id
  add_index: :fvs, :empreses.id 
  add_index: :dados_inspecao, :quantidade_errors
end
```

Then `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and you should be good to go.

In general, any time you see `Seq Scan` in your postgres `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, it means the database is scanning without an index.  Sequential (non-index) scans are much slower than Index scans.  Adding an index to the column that is being scanned will usually speed things up.

After making the above changes, if you run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` again, I think you will find all of your scans are index scans and the query will run much faster.

Finally, in the future, you can add an index to a new column by adding `index: true` to the line of your migration that creates the column.  All of your foreigns keys (i.e. columns that reference the id of another table) should have an index.

Comment: Hey guy I liked your solution but not work here, I think this increase the performance but is very slow yet.

Comment: I recommend you analyze your solution and my solution using Greg Navis' recommendation outline in his comment to your question.  I.e call `to_sql` and use postgres to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.  This will show you where your query is slow.  I am guessing you are missing an index somewhere.  All of your ids, foriegn_keys and `quantidade_errors` should have an index if you want this to be fast.

Post the query analysis, and I may be able to recommend a solution.

Comment: Oks I did edit the question and put the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output

Comment: Oh yeah EXPLAIN ANALYZE help me so much thanks, and I did add the index that you recommend, but the real problem was scoped query: the query verifies many times for **"empresas_id" = 44093** I removed this and works very well and fast. Thanks